# Putting space between two buttons vertically and horizontally in desktop and responsive mode

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm using WordPress so no CSS solution is best. I need to add space between two buttons in my article.

This image below shows how they look like in a wide screen like desktop.
[image: Buttons side by side]

This shows lack of vertical space between them in a mobile screen.
[image: Buttons on top of one another]

How to add the vertical space in between the buttons without CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do styling, so css is there for this purpose. Why you cannot edit the css in your wordpress site? You can give them a margin-button set in the css.
You can edit the style.css in your theme, or you can go Design - Customizer - Custom styling, there should be a way to add your own css.

.your_buttton_class { margin-bottom: 0.2em; }

Your get the class if you use the inspector (right click) in your browser.

You get also set the styling definitions to the html tags directly in the html file, but this is not good practice.

If it is not possible to edit the stylesheet, can you give some more information about your site and your access to it? Thanks!

So with the Ultimate Shortcodes Plugin you are using, refereing to the docs:
https://getshortcodes.com/docs/button/

Adjust this in your wordpress editor:

```
[su_button class="space_to_bottom"]Button[/su_button]
```

And in your CSS:

```
.space_to_bottom {
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}
```

Margin-Bottom is for creating space around elements:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: I'm using Ultimate Shortcode plugin to generate the buttons. To be precise [su_button]

Comment: You can give them a class within the shortcode https://getshortcodes.com/docs/button/

Comment: Btw, the issue is not about margin. But white spacing between buttons.